# How to call checkout sucesspage with ajax request

Tags: magento2, checkout-page

i have created some extra steps on checkout page. The last step is to show successpage.Is there any  way to call successpage layout using ajax request on that step? or is there any other way to make successpage as a checkout step?

Comment: Do you want to just show the sucess page or you want to redirect customer on that page?

Comment: actually i have re-designed sucess page. now i want to show that page as step of checkout.like this http://prntscr.com/ndokhx

Comment: If you want to show this, then you need to design this from scratch, no need to call orignal sucess phtml there. This is better options for you.